# Optimize query with loads of IN entries

Tags: mysql

I have quite a massive query that I want to optimize, it consists of 1 table request and 5 table left joins.
This query takes 0.3428 sec to complete ( Results: 4,340 total, Query took 0.3428 sec)
I am working with about 10000 entries which will definitely grow.

Now the query by it self is not the problem it is the IN statements that is the biggest problem.

1. I have 2 IN statements
2. Both are in the WHERE statement
3. For this specific page load both have a big amount of ID's, 3344 amount of id entries Example: (99, 1, 5, 8458, ...)
4. Both IN statements will have the same set of 3344 ID's Example: ((cf.catid IN ( 99, 1, 5, 8458, ... ) AND cf.cid=c.id) OR p.category IN ( 99, 1, 5, 8458, ... ))

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, c.id AS pCid, c.name AS cName, p.name, p.seo, 
    p.description AS pDescription, cd.description,
    p.category, p.archive, cf.catid, cf.pid, p.order_nr, 
    c.order_nr AS cOrder, c.seo AS cSeo, cat.name AS catName, 
    cat.order_id, pr.price, pr.sale_price, pr.sale_expiry,
    IF( pr.sale_price > 0, pr.sale_price, pr.price ) AS `oPrices`,
    pr.member_price, p.`set`, p.get_the_look,
    c.from_text_price, c.thumb, c.code AS colour_code, 
    p.code AS product_code, p.supplier_part_number, 
    p.oem_part_number, p.make, p.model, p.year, p.sub_model
FROM 
    products p
    LEFT JOIN category_featured cf ON p.id=cf.pid
    LEFT JOIN colours c ON c.pid=p.id
    LEFT JOIN colour_descriptions cd ON c.id=cd.colour_id
    LEFT JOIN category cat ON cat.id=p.category
    LEFT JOIN pricing pr ON pr.cid=c.id
WHERE 
    (
        (cf.catid IN ( .. 3344 ID entries .. ) AND cf.cid=c.id) OR p.category IN ( .. 3344 ID entries .. )
    )
    AND p.archive='0'

    AND p.status='1' AND c.status='1' 
    AND c.archive='0'
    AND cat.status IN (1,2)

GROUP BY `c`.`id`
ORDER BY `oPrices` DESC
```

Is there a better way to do a check for specific ID's in a table using the IN statement or maybe use a different check all together?

Speed is the main issue here, I want to achieve the best performance possible.

So far what I did and how some of the settings are set:

- I created indexes for those tables (only the columns that are INT (integers) that are used in this query have indexes)
- Some tables are MyISAM some are InnoDB (other tables that are not used in the query have a relation with a few tables that are in the query so they had to be InnoDB)
- no relations between the tables in the query exist
- to run the query I use PHP and MySQLI

Thanks

UPDATE!!!!

I noticed why the query is so slow the new column that I create, using the IF statement `oPrices` and then useage of "ORDER BY `oPrices` DESC" makes the query slow, once I remove it the query only takes 0.00009 of a sec which is amazing!!! But now I wont get the correctly ordered data and if even I do the ordering with PHP I will have to create a new pagination function which is not ideal.

Comment: Do you have *composite* indexes on the tables that are mentioned multiple times in your `WHERE` clause, e.g. products?

Comment: From where do these long lists of IDs come?

Comment: Hi Alain, Yes I have created indexes for all the table columns that are used in the WHERE statement because all of them are INT. The ID's come based on a page request made, so I know the ID's from other functions.

Comment: I had asked about *composite* indexes.  Assuming that there isn't a user who is selecting 3,000 items from a drop down, if the values are in the database, can you recreate the list inside the database?  Much better than way.

Comment: No we are not using composite indexes, they make everything even slower. The problem is that I cannot create a list in the database of those ID's. From the looks of things the best way is to insert into a temporary table as @devek said but as I havent used them I am not sure If I'll be able to use them correctlly.

Comment: Indexes may make `INSERT` slower, but a good composite index will make your query faster.  NSOMN.

Comment: I understand what you mean but in my situation I couldn't improve using composite indexes it just made it slower (didn't mater what combination I used)

Comment: I love SQL from [infinite monkeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IN` can make a query very difficult to optimize as the index **may** not be used (you can verify this by using `EXPLAIN`). An alternative approach would be to load these IDs into a temporary table and then perform a `JOIN`.

From this link:

http://explainextended.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-in-mysql-in-list-vs-temporary-table/

> We see that for a large list of parameters, passing them in a
>   temporary table is much faster that as a constant list, while for
>   small lists performance is almost the same.
>
> Using a temporary table is the best way to pass large arrays of
>   parameters in MySQL.

Comment: Hi @davek I haven't used mysql temporary tables before but from a quick look on google it looks like it will require to run more queries just to insert data into a temporary table and of course to create one before hand. Is that correct?